# ¿Es posible crear de forma dinámica un DataFrame de PANDAS a partir de los campos de unas tuplas, mediante un ciclo for?

Tags: python, bucle-for, csv, dataframe

Código:

```
import pandas as pd

cve_pe = []

idiscap = tuple(datos['DISCAPACIDAD'])
ddiscap = valores_unicos(idiscap)
isexo = tuple(datos['SEXO'])
dsexo = valores_unicos(isexo)

idx_discap =pd.DataFrame({'PROG_EDUC':cve_pe})

for d in ddiscap: # MUL VIS AUd MOT
    d_t = d
    if d_t !='NINGUNA':
        for s in dsexo: # M F
            s_t = s
            n_c = str(d_t) + ' ' + str(s_t)
            ndiscapacidad = contar_discap(dtemp, d_t, s_t)
            print(n_c + ' ' + str(ndiscapacidad))
            idx_discap = idx_discap.assign(n_c=[])
            # Aquí debería de crearse las tuplas [] nombradas como n_c y vacias pero la nombra n_c y no la etiqueta de la discapacidad sexo
            # Agregarse al DataFrame idx_discap
# Una vez creado el DataFrame completo se sale de los ciclos y se realizan las consultas para cada columna y se rellena los datos.
```

La idea es que aquí se vayan agregando las columnas nombradas con el contenido de la variable n_c y que posteriormente se vaya rellenando ese mismo arreglo con valores producto de selecciones de datos de los DataFrames generados con dtemp
Las etiquetas de los campos surgen de la selección de campos clave para y son del tipo
AUD_M
AUD_F
MOT_M
MOT_F
MUL_M
MUL_F
VIS_M
VIS_F
Los valores que almacenaran esos campos etiquetados son numéricos finalmente la idea es crear un DataFrame que quede de la forma:

| PROG_EDUC | AUD_M | AUD_F | MOT_M | MOT_F | MUL_M | MUL_F | VIS_M | VIS_F |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| '01M MED' | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| '03M MPL' | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 |
| '07M MQS' | 1 | 0 | 3 | 1 | 0 | 1 | 2 | 4 |

Mi duda es sies posible hacer la creación de forma dinámica o será necesario crear el DataFrame antes y solo intentar rellenarlo.
El problema es que no se sabe en cada periodo de consulta cuantos programas educativos habrá en el listado, o cuantas discapacidades declaradas.
Estas consultas son parte de un intento por crear información de indicadores escolares de forma automatizada tomando como insumo el resultado de una consulta a BD Oracle y la exportación de la misma a un archivo CSV.
La salida en vez de crear la tabla mostrada solo crea una columna nombrada como n_p

Empty DataFrame
Columns: [PROG_EDUC, n_c]
Index: []

Ojalá pueda encontrar ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

No pude lograr crear el DataFrame de forma dinámica, ya que aún poseo poca experiencia en el lenguaje, supongo que si debe ser posible, lo que hice fue crear una estructura que contenía los campos que requiero obtener y rellenarla mediante ciclos for anidados.

```
idx_discap = pd.DataFrame({'MODALIDAD':df, 'NIVEL':df, 'SISTEMA':df, 'PROG_EDUC':df, 'DISCAP':df, 'SEXO':df, 'CANT':df})
```

Esta este DataFrame es el almacenamiento temporal de los datos que voy recolectando sobre todos los tipos de discapacidades reportadas por los alumnos inscritos según su programa educativo y sexo, en los ciclos for se recorreran todas las discapacidades reportadas que obtuvimos en la consulta y para cada sexo se obtendra el conteo de alumnos que la reportaron.

```
def valores_unicos(lista):
if isinstance(lista,(tuple,list)):
    unicos = []
    for l in lista:
        if l not in unicos:
            unicos.append(l)
    return unicos
```

Con esta función obtengo el catalogo de discapacidades (el encabezado de mi tabla) y sus sub encabezados (sexos), que es lo que me permitirá forma la tabla.

```
def contar_discap(prog_educ, discap, sex):
    prog_educ = prog_educ[prog_educ['DISCAPACIDAD']==discap]
    prog_educ = prog_educ[prog_educ['SEXO']==sex]
    ndiscap = prog_educ['MATRICULA'].count()
    return ndiscap
```

La función anterior me permite contabilizar los alumnos de cada tipo de discapacidad por sexo.

```
for d in ddiscap:
    if d !='NINGUNA' and d !='Ninguna':
        for s in dsexo:
            idx_discap = idx_discap.append({'MODALIDAD':itemp['MODALIDAD'].max(), 'NIVEL':itemp['NIVEL'].max(), 'SISTEMA':itemp['SISTEMA'].max(), 'PROG_EDUC':p, 'DISCAP':d, 'SEXO':s, 'CANT':contar_discap(itemp, d, s)}, ignore_index=True)
```

Los ciclos for anidados usan la función para ambos sexos por cada programa educativo y dichos cálculos se agregan al DataFrame previamente declarado, el cual contendra todos los datos necesarios para armar nuestra tabla.

Finalmente una vez que se termina el ciclo que recorre todos los programas educativos idx_dicapacidad será la fuente de los datos que permitira crear un DataFrame nuevo ya organizado según la tabla presentada en la pregunta inicial mediante la instrucción "pivot" de la siguiente forma:

```
idx_discap_clasif = idx_discap.pivot_table( values = 'CANT', index = ['MODALIDAD', 'NIVEL', 'SISTEMA', 'PROG_EDUC'], columns = ['DISCAP', 'SEXO']).sort_values(by = ['MODALIDAD', 'NIVEL', 'SISTEMA', 'PROG_EDUC'], ascending = [False, True, True, True])
```

Con esto simplemente debemos exportar el DataFrame resultante a Excel mediante las instrucciones que Pandas posee para este propósito:

```
with pd.ExcelWriter('indicadores.xlsx') as writer:
    idx_discap_clasif.to_excel(writer, sheet_name = 'discapacidad')
```

El resultado es una hoja de Excel como sigue:

[image: Hoja de Excel resultante de las operaciones anteriores sobre los DataFrames y sus datos]

El paso final sería dar formato a la hoja para poder entregarla a quienes la requieren y graficar en su caso para cada P.E. y discapacidad según convenga.

Comment: Tengo la sensación de que todos esos ciclos for pueden ser eliminados, simplemente teniendo todos los datos en un solo gran dataframe y aplicando operaciones de tipo `groupby()`, `.count()`, etc sobre el mismo. Me gustaría poder hacer una prueba de la idea para ponerla en una respuesta, pero es que no tengo claro aún de dónde llegan los datos "de entrada". Mencionas una consulta a oracle ¿qué retornaría esa consulta? ¿Son ya todos los datos que después procesas, o requieres ir haciendo más consultas? Si es el primer caso, puedes proporcionar un ejemplo de lo que tendrías?

Comment: Creo que lo que te estoy preguntando es en esencia un volcado de la variable `datos` de tu pregunta original. Si son muchos puedes recortarlo para que sean menos, o poner un enlace a algún lugar donde poder descargarlos en formato csv por ejemplo.,Si contienen datos confidenciales puedes "ocultarlos", por ejemplo con `datos["Nombre"] = "ocultado"`, etc Todo eso no es necesario para los cálculos.

Comment: Los datos provienen de un archivo CSV exportado de una consulta a una BD Oracle  12c, de la cual solo poseo arcceso de lectura de parte del esquema, son datos de matrícula escolar, por lo general son 30  x  4000. No requiero hacer más consultas Estuve leyendo sobre lo que sugieres  no me quedo muy claro como usar groupby() como implementar varias condiciones, ejemplo: prog_educ = '01C', grado == 2, grupo =='A1' Sexo == 'M'. pero una vez que finalice mi promer versión me daré a la tarea probar esas alternativas que sugieres @abulafia

Answer (score 0):

Efectivamente, todos esos ciclos pueden evitarse usando las siguientes instrucciones.

```
#  Matricula con discapacidad nuevo ingreso
matrdiscapni = dinscrito[dinscrito['MATRICULADE']=='CIERRE']
matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni[matrdiscapni['DISCAPACIDAD']!='NINGUNA']
matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni[matrdiscapni['T_INS']=='NI']
matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni[matrdiscapni['E_EXT']=='ADM']
matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni[matrdiscapni['E_INT']=='ADM']
if len(matrdiscapni)!=0:
    matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni.groupby(["MODALIDAD", "NIVEL", "SISTEMA", "PROG_EDUC", "DISCAPACIDAD", "SEXO"])["MATRICULA"].aggregate("count")
    matrdiscapni = pd.DataFrame(matrdiscapni)
    matrdiscapni = matrdiscapni.pivot_table(values = "MATRICULA", index = ["MODALIDAD", "NIVEL", "SISTEMA", "PROG_EDUC"], columns = ["DISCAPACIDAD", "SEXO"], fill_value = 0)
matrdiscapni.sort_values(by=["MODALIDAD", "NIVEL", "SISTEMA", "PROG_EDUC"], ascending = [False, True, True, True])
```

Obteniéndose el mismo resultado que con las instrucciones anteriores, pero con menos código.

Comment: Qué bueno que te hayas autorrespondido, y luego de tanto tiempo. No olvides [aceptar](/help/accepted-answer) tu respuesta. Tampoco olvides referenciar tu respuesta "anterior" en esta respuesta, ya que no todos ven las respuestas de las preguntas en orden cronológico.